# Can't make a .py file into a .exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, file-conversion, modulenotfounderror

I'm somewhat new to python, so it would be nice if this was explained simply, if you can.
I'm trying to make a py file (main.py) into a exe file. I've followed this tutorial (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/) as well as a youtube one, which did the same thing. My project has several modules. The conversion works, but if I try to open it, it tells me: (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'). I would assume it does this for the rest of them if it gets the chance to. I don't know how to fix this and it would be nice if I could have a exe file so I could share programs with friends that don't have python installed.  (I'm using pyinstaller for the process, same as the tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

`requests` is a 3rd party library. I assume when you created the .exe, you did not "assembled" together your script with its dependencies.

According to the linked tutorial, you should check the `pyinstaller`'s config and try to give `pyinstaller` the missing packages and somehow compile it with them, e.g.

> ```
> For any missing package:
> pyinstaller --hidden-import 'package_name' --onefile 'filename.py'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just install `requests`:

```
pip install requests
```

Then you'll be able to bundle the script into an exe, provided there aren't any other missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question either the `requests` module isn't installed or pyinstaller can't find the module!

If module isn't Installed then open up your terminal/Command Prompt and execute the follow command:

```
pip install requests
```

But if module is installed then what you can do is manually specify Pyinstaller which module to include also

so to compile it to exe use this command

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import 'requests' --onefile 'main.py'
```

Here the option `--hidden-import` means it will import the module `requests` also and `--onefile` means it you will get a single Exe file which will contain everything

Note! if you use `--onefile` this can effect your time taken to start your program!

Thanks

Edit:

According to the tutorial it shows you to open "PowerShell" but I recommend you to use "CMD" for this purpose!